# Conditional Probability and Partitions

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have a question from Probability and Statistics - 4th edition bu DeGroot. It is example 2.2.10 on page 61.

*"Achieving a High Score. Suppose that a person plays a game in which his score must be one of the 50 numbers 1, 2,..., 50 and that each of these 50 numbers is equally likely to be his score. The first time he plays the game, his score is X. He then continues to play the game until he obtains another score Y such that Y ≥ X. We will assume that, conditional on previous plays, the 50 scores remain equally likely on all subsequent
plays. 
We shall determine the probability of the event A that Y = 50.
For each i = 1,..., 50, let Bi be the event that X = i. Conditional on Bi, the
value of Y is equally likely to be any one of the numbers i, i + 1,..., 50. Since each
of these (51 − i) possible values for Y is equally likely, it follows that
Pr(A|Bi) = Pr(Y = 50|Bi) = 1/(51-i).
Furthermore, since the probability of each of the 50 values of X is 1/50, it follows that Pr(Bi) = 1/50 for all i."*

My question is if about an intuitive understanding of the material as it took me a while to get it. Are we effectively taking the sum from Bi =1,... Bi=50 of Pr(A AND B)? It seems as though this is whats happened from the working but I wanted to make sure this is the case.

[In essence, is Pr(A) the same as Pr(Y=50 AND Bi)?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hwUl.png)

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: Pr(Y=50) is the sum of those intersection probabilities Pr(Y=50 and Bi), since the events B1, ... B50 form a partition of the sample space.

Comment: That is what I thought, thank you for clarifying!